# Swift: why closure function is called to late

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, closures

I have 2 functions:

```
class ProductController: NSObject {

    var products = [Product]()

    func getData(){

        let json = JSONParser()
        let path = "http://localhost:8888/myApi/product/read.php"

        json.getRequest(url: path) { (products) in
            self.products = products
            print("closure")
            print(self.products)
        }
    }

    func getPr() -> [Product]{
        return self.products
    }
}
```

And i'm calling:

```
 let pc = ProductController()
 pc.getData()
 print(pc.getPr())
```

But the calling of `pc.getData()` is always last, so i get `[]` from `pc.getPr()`. How can i get the products from `getData()` before calling `getPr()`?

Comment: You noticed its called "too late", that's one point that many debutant don't. Now, the concept you are missing is "asynchrone". There are plenty of question about that on SO, how to manage them in Swift with Closures.

Answer (score 1):

You can try completions

```
func getData(completion: @escaping (_ anyData: [Product]) -> Void) {
  let json = JSONParser()
  let path = "http://localhost:8888/myApi/product/read.php"

  json.getRequest(url: path) { (products) in
  self.products = products
  print("closure")
  print(self.products)
  completion(products)

}
```

And call it like this

```
pc.getData() { products in

    print(products)
    print(pc.getPr())
}
```

Comment: I can do this by simply calling :

 json.getRequest(url: path) { (products) in
    self.products = products
    print("closure")
    print(self.products)
    }

I just want to assign the result products in instance variable self.products when i call getData()

Comment: The code already did this but you can't use it's value until the completion finishes this is an asynchronous call

Comment: i did that:
let pc = ProductController()
        
        pc.getData(completion: {products in
            
            print()
        })
        print(pc.getPr())

The getPr() is still called before getData()

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing HTTPRequest task, your device sending request to your server and then device waiting for server response, in the meantime server taking your request, processing and preparing data for you, after that it is sending response and data to you. SO after your request it will take some time to get response and you never know the exact time.
Whenever you need to do some task after getting Response, you should define your task inside completion handler what @Sh_Khan said.

Beside this if you want to do something after your variable data changed you can use `Swift Property observers` `didSet` and `wilSet`
ex(iswift.org):

```
var a : [Int] = [0,1,4]{
didSet{
    print(a)
}
}
a = [10, 20, 30]
a.append(60)
```

Output:
`[10, 20, 30]
 [10, 20, 30, 60]`